# Controlling a Canon Powershot with a CGI/Bash Script

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy, cgi

I am trying to control my camera through the program chdkptp by using a CGI/Bash script.
I have successfully controlled the camera by typing in the commands by hand:

```
pi@camerapi /var/www/chdkptp $ sudo ./chdkptp-sample.sh
___> connect          # connect to camera
com> rec          # switch to record mode (picture taking)
com 1> shoot          # take a picture
com 2> q          # quit the program
pi@camerapi /var/www/chdkptp $
```

Now I want a CGI/Bash script to do this for me.
So far what I have done is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/chdkptp
./chdkptp-sample.sh -c # The -c auto connects when the script is started.
```

I currently have a topic on the Raspberry Pi fourm but it is not getting replies.
Raspberry Pi link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=113847

Comment: Maybe the script is a lot faster than typing by hand. What happens if you insert a delay (sleep) ?